# Embed mobile friendly website as iPhone app

Tags: ios

Let's say we have a mobile-friendly website www.mywebsite.com that I want to quickly turn into an iPhone app. Would I just create an empty iPhone app with a full screen web browser control and point it to www.mywebsite.com? Or is there something more to it...

FYI I have no iPhone development experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with `UIWebView`.  However Apple take a dim view of applications like this and you could well find your application rejected.  [The App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) state:

> Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected